# Which tag should be used for gaming?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we've the following tags related to gaming:
[ai-games](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai-games), [gaming](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming), [go-game](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go-game), [game-theory](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-theory), [game-play](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-play), [games](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games).

Can we decide on one or two to stick with related to gaming? Which one would be the most suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there should be two tags here:

**[gaming](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming) and [game-theory](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-theory).**

[gaming](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming) is for how AIs are used *in games*.

[game-theory](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-theory) should be used for AIs *playing games*.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with [gaming](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming). It's implied that questions on an AI site will be about AI, so there's no need to specify that in a tag. The gerund form makes it clear that gaming is something the AIs are doing.

We can add tags for specific games (like Go) if they become big topics.

Answer (score 2):

Some of these tags seem related but I think [game-theory](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-theory) has a well-known definition (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory))

> the study of mathematical models of conflict and cooperation between
>   intelligent rational decision-makers

and it's applied in other fields besides AI.

IMO there should also be different tags for `AI that's used in games` and `AI that plays games`, the first may correspond to [gaming](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming) [games](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) or so and I would call the second [game-play](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-play).

Moreover [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)) refers to that specific board game, which had for long been considered as the only game that humans play better than machines until the AI [AlphaGo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaGo) came into play. So [go-game](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go-game) seems to be particularly for [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)).

So IMO at least [game-theory](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-theory) [go-game](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go-game) have clear definitions, and among the others there should be separate tags for `AI that's used in games` and `AI that plays games`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bit of a difference between [games](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) and [gaming](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming). I wouldn't call playing Go or chess gaming. I might call it, depending on the context, playing a game.

On the other hand, playing a game such as World of Warcraft or Plants vs. Zombies, I would call gaming. (not that I do it...)